# UITextfield with secureTextEntry bug in ios 14

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, uitextfield

Now I use `uitextfield` for my password field and enable `isSecureTextEntry = true`
but I found a bug, when I typing other languages ( not english ). It not show secure character ( • ) but I got blank charater instead like this..

[image]

It happend on iOS 14.5 but on 12.0 It working fine.
Has anyone seen this issue? Thank you.